# gnuplot "matrix with image" with a fixed colour for a certain value

Tags: matrix, colors, gnuplot, colorbox, palette

With gnuplot, I am plotting a matrix stored in a file with the following commands:

```
set title "Matrix"
set xrange[-0.5:9.5]
set yrange[9.5:-0.5]
set pm3d map
unset key
unset surface
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set out "matrix.eps"
set palette defined (-1 "#A52A2A", 0 "white", 1 "green" )
splot "matcorrel" matrix with image
```

The matrix has positive and negative values, and I would like to put the zero values always in white, positive values in the green zone of the palette and negative values in brown. The positive values are bigger than the negative ones, so gnuplot is not placing the zero in white.

I have tried with `set cbrange` but I have only managed to modify the extreme colors, not being able to fix the central one.

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnuplot cannot autoscale symmetrically around some value. You must use e.g. `stats` to determine the cbrange yourself:

```
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
unset key

set term postscript eps enhanced color
set out "matrix.eps"

stats "matcorrel" matrix using 3 nooutput
cbmax = (abs(STATS_min) > abs(STATS_max) ? abs(STATS_min) : abs(STATS_max))
set cbrange [-cbmax:cbmax]
set palette defined (-1 "#A52A2A", 0 "white", 1 "green" )

plot "matcorrel" matrix with image
```

If you want to use different limits for the positive and negative values, but keep the zero in white you can use

```
stats "matcorrel" matrix using 3 nooutput
set cbrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]
set palette defined (STATS_min "#A52A2A", 0 "white", STATS_max "green" )
```

Note, that you don't need to use pm3d if you plot `with image`. Since you're plotting a heatmap, you can directly use `plot`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly.Could it be possible to put the Zero in white, and use different limits for the positive and the negative values?